# add total count inside stack labels grouped stacked column chart- Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a stacked grouped column highcharts like
http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/d9yb1yy1/

currently in stackLabels I'm adding the stack name, now I am trying to add the total count of a column at the top of every column. however when I add them into the dataLabels, I see other series of labels also showing up.

```
 plotOptions: {
          column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
          },
  formatter : function() {
              return "<span>" + this.total + "</span>";
            }
        },
```

this will show the labels on every stacked series. I want to simple show one count / column in the chart
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add stack-total values by stack labels and try to use the `grouped_categories` plugin to add the stack name.

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: [{
            name: 'category1',
            categories: ['A', 'B']
        }, {
            name: 'category2',
            categories: ['C', 'D']
        }]
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L0pko9h5/

**Docs:** https://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/

---

The other way is to use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class and manually render the labels.

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Comment: Thank for your help... my requirement is a bit more different in terms of - http://jsfiddle.net/d_paul/d9yb1yy1/ where I want every column to have label eg:  in my fiddle- 2014 and 2015 are repeated as stack labels for every column in the chart and they are grouped under "Apples" "Orange"- Is this layout possible with in the grouped-chart plugin ?

Comment: Hi @user1234, Highcharts allows to use only one stack label per stack, so you need to find some other way to add the second label. The grouped categories plugin is one of the possibilities, but it may not work for you. Plase try to use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` as I mentioned in the answer above.